# Regarding SendClassification.CustomerKey

Tags: soap-api, marketing-cloud, .net

This is regarding Exact Target API terminology. I am currently trying to test TriggeredSend in the APIStarterkit project in .NET. I am currently learning and testing samples.

Can any body advice what is CustomerKey here in below code ? I didn't understand what is this and why we require this ? Where do we find this value ?

```
tsd.SendClassification = new SendClassification();
tsd.SendClassification.CustomerKey = "222322";
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the documentation on [send classifications](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-GB/documentation/exacttarget/admin/send_classifications/)

Customer Key is the unique identifier for the send classification you want to use.